# Using pywinauto.top_window() hangs when using it with threads

Tags: python, multithreading, com, pywinauto, comtypes

If I create a thread that all it does is connect to some process and get its top window, then the program hangs.

I debugged it a little and it seems to get stuck in *comtypes._compointer_base.from_params*. This is the whole traceback:

```
...
-> self.top_win = self.app.top_window()
  c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py(1095)top_window()
-> backend=self.backend.name)
  c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\findwindows.py(197)find_elements()
-> cache_enable=True)
  c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\uia_element_info.py(272)children()
-> return self._get_elements(IUIA().tree_scope["children"], cond, cache_enable)
  c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\uia_element_info.py(261)_get_elements()
-> ptrs_array = self._element.FindAll(tree_scope, cond)
> c:\python27\lib\site-packages\comtypes\__init__.py(970)from_param()
-> return value
```

after typing step in pdb, it shows this and then freezes:

```
(Pdb) s
--Return--
> c:\python27\lib\site-packages\comtypes\__init__.py(970)from_param()-><POINTER... 41308a0>
-> return value
```

It seems that the problem is in using comtypes with threads, I tried to call *pythoncom.CoInitialize()* in the calling thread (and also in main) but it didn't help.

What can be done here?

Thanks.

Comment: Hmm... Good question. Maybe there are some pitfalls for threading in MS UI Automation also... If you could find answer, it might be twice useful because we're planning to do some threading for future "record-replay" implementation.

Comment: One more thing I suspect is that pywinauto creates only one `IUIA()` object (yeah, it's singleton). I know it's kinda anti-pattern, but I made it as a workaround for another problem which is probably not workarounded anyway. :) I'll think how to make `IUIA()` instantiating once per thread or allow unrestricted number of instances...

Comment: [Issue #394](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/issues/394) is a reminder for us.

Comment: Thanks.. For now, I made a workaround to make it single threaded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pywinauto==0.6.4` uses multi-threading mode (MTA) for COM objects by default. Just upgrade it by `pip install -U pywinauto` and check if it works for you.